# Const char * str issue

Tags: c, string, char

I have to use fputs to print something and fputs take "const char *str" to print out.
I have 3 strings to print(I don't care if it's strings or char[]) as *str.
I dont know the right way to do it. I used 3 string and I added them to one but is not working. I also tried to convert string to char* but nothing is working!
Any recommendations?

```
struct passwd* user_info = getpwuid(getuid()); 
struct utsname uts;
 uname(&uts);
```

I want my char const *str = user_info->pw_name + '@' + uts.nodename

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
/* 1 for '@' and 1 for terminating NULL */
int size = strlen(user_info->pw_name) + strlen(uts.nodename) + 2;
char* s = malloc(size);

strcpy(s, user_info->pw_name);
strcat(s, "@");
strcat(s, uts.nodename);


/* Free when done. */
free(s);
```

EDIT:

If C++ you can use `std::string`:

```
std::string s(user_info->pw_name);
s += "@";
s += uts.nodename;

// s.c_str(); this will return const char* to the string.
```

Comment: i get 'invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘char*’

Comment: While the code is correct, the [use of `strcat` is dangerous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936468/why-does-msvc-consider-stdstrcat-to-be-unsafe-c) and should be avoided (same for `strcpy`).

Comment: Guessing this is a C++ source so cast return value from `malloc()` to `char*`. If you are using C++ then recommend using `std::string` instead of managing memory yourself.

Comment: @user776720 Where ? Perhaps you're compiling the code as C++, instead of C.

Comment: fix it with     char* s = (char*)malloc(size);

Comment: @user776720: Which of two solutions are you using? The C or C++ one?

Comment: Take heed of @DarkDust comment regarding the unsafety of `strcat()`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a new string for that. I have no idea why you need the `fputs` restriction, but I assume that even if you can't/don't want to use `fprintf`, you still have `snprintf` available. You'd then do it like this:

```
char *new_str;
int new_length;

// Determine how much space we'll need.
new_length = snprintf(NULL, "%s@%s", user_info->pw_name, uts.nodename);
if (new_length < 0) {
    // Handle error here.
}
// Need to allocate one more character for the NULL termination.
new_str = malloc(new_length + 1);
// Write new string.
snprintf(new_str, "%s@%s", user_info->pw_name, uts.nodename);
```